# Problem with fetch data from api to client in angular

Tags: angular

I have a problem with get data to the client using httpClient in my web app.
when i check server everything is ok in
[Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SR733.png)
, but client in angular return empty object.
thats my ICalendar interface:

```
export interface ICalendar {
  calendarName: string;
  userId: number;
  training: Array<{
    trainingTittle: string;
    date: string;
    excercises: Array<{
      excerciseName: string,
      numOfRepeat: number
   }>
  }>;
}
```

and thats how i get data in service:

```
 export class CalendarService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  public getAllTrainings() {
    return this.http.get<ICalendar[]>('https://localhost:5001/api/calendar');
  }
```

and thats how call method looks like:

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
this.calendarService.getAllTrainings()
  .subscribe(data => {
    this.trainings = data;
  });
console.log(this.trainings);
```

but log is empty
[console log of object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZT2Ey.png)

and thats how it looks like in [database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0k5N6.png)

someone know how to handle it?

Comment: Any errors in the console? How does the network request look like in your browser developer tool ?

Comment: Since it is async call, your console.log execute first and returning empty. but you can console.log inside your subscribe and see

Comment: use console.log inside subscribe i.e. subscribe(data => { console.log(data); this.trainings = data });

Answer (score 0):

use console.log inside subscribe

```
ngOnInit(): void {
   this.calendarService.getAllTrainings().subscribe(data => {
    console.log(this.trainings);
    this.trainings = data;
  });
```

as calling an api is an asynchronous task it will take some time to get response, if you use console.log outside the subscriber then the control flow won't wait for the api call resulting in printing initial value of `this.trainings` variable,

if you call it inside subscriber the control flow will execute console.log after the api response has been completed hence console.log will get printed with values.